# Difference between TryGetValue() and GetorCreate()?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I'm making a web app with ASP.NET MVC and Angular. To cache results for the main dashboard I'm using the inbuilt IMemoryCache.

I'm using GetorCreate for its Async version, but what's the real difference between TryGetValue() and GetorCreate()? Don't they both try and get the value from cache, but if it isn't we can make it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the future this could be useful for someone.

> **GetOrCreate():** By using the cache.GetOrCreate() you can check whether the passed key exists or not and if it does not exist then
>   will create new cache key value.

```
cache.GetOrCreate()<string>(“username”, entry => { return “admin”; });
```

> **TryGetValue():** By using the cache.TryGetValue() we can check whether the key exists or not. Here the main difference between
>   cache.GetOrCreate() and cache.TryGetValue() method is that TryGet()
>   method will only check whether the key exists or not whereas
>   GetOrCreate() method will cache whether the key exists or not and if
>   it doesn’t exist then can create a new one.

```
cache.TryGetValue()<string>(“username”, out string username);
```

But there are not so many differences between two approaches

Link's: 
https://www.itpathsolutions.com/know-about-in-memory-caching-asp-net-core/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cache-guidelines